# Kura deployment package fails with 'bundle already present in other packages'

Tags: osgi, osgi-bundle, kura

I am trying to run a Kura sample from the [basic kura tutorial](http://reference.bitreactive.com/tutorials/kura-tutorial.html) named: *(Level 3) Kura Configuration Example*

 I got the sources, builded it with the 'Java OSGi Bundle for Eclipse Kura'. It generated a .dpp file. I used 'Quick build' to generate a .dp file.
Everything seems to work fine until I am trying to deploy it to a Kura session installed on a RPi. 

On the RPi, Kura is up and running.

I tried to install the .dp but it yields the err('bundle already present in other package'):

```
Error
Mon Feb 05 17:40:37 EET 2018
Failed to install deployment package: 
org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin.DeploymentException: Bundle 
'com.bitreactive.blocks.osgi.runtime/2.6.1 already present in other 
deployment packages!

org.tigris.mtoolkit.iagent.IAgentException: Failed to install 
deployment package: org.osgi.service.deploymentadmin.DeploymentException: Bundle 'com.bitreactive.blocks.osgi.runtime/2.6.1 already present in other deployment packages!
at org.tigris.mtoolkit.iagent.internal.DeploymentManagerImpl.installDeploymentPackage(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:172)
at org.tigris.mtoolkit.osgimanagement.dp.logic.InstallDeploymentOperation.doOperation(InstallDeploymentOperation.java:98)
at org.tigris.mtoolkit.osgimanagement.dp.logic.RemoteDeploymentOperation.run(RemoteDeploymentOperation.java:49)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: Trying uninstalling any *.dp files currently installed. Then, from the OSGi console, enter the command ss. Remove any com.bitreactive.* bundles installed in the framework. Then, trying installing your *.dp file.

Comment: I fixed it by re-installing the entire kura app, which is not ideal. I was assuming that I can somehow identify the package/s that are using the same bundles, or reuse the same bundles somehow.